# Reproducible image embeddings from NN (Resnet50)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I need to implement a service which generates image embeddings with neural networks to be used for image similarity comparisons.

The problem I am facing is how to make sure the embeddings will be reproducible over long periods of time.

I am using a pre-trained Resnet50 model to generate ima embeddings of dimension 2048.

Currently this is done with python library, Towhee https://github.com/towhee-io/towhee
the below code create an array of floats size 2048.

```
towhee_vectors = towhee.glob(*all_frame_paths).exception_safe() \
                        .image_decode() \
                        .image_embedding.timm(model_name="resnet50") \
                        .drop_empty() \
                        .tensor_normalize() \
                        .to_list()
```

I believe Towhee downloads a version of pre-trained models (weights) and this removes it from my control.
I would like to store weights and model architecture locally so that I can always reproduce it

Is anyone aware of any such solutions?

Comment: talk to the company whose service you are using. -- the only way to make this "reproducible" is to make sure your network's weights don't change. if you change them locally, you could just run your inference locally. if that service supports telling them exactly what weights to use (like with a hash for the weights file), idk, maybe?

Comment: the service provider you speak of is a pythonlibrary https://github.com/towhee-io/towhee. it uses torchvision under the hood I believe. Yes gettting the weights and the model architecture locally is what I thought of as well. But I would also need to find exactly which layers to use for feature extraction.

Answer (score 1):

towhee uses [timm](https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models/) library under the hood but does not provide a way to specify the checkpoint path which could be used for loading of local weights.

But you can circumvent it by code patching.

1. [download the weights from here](https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models/blob/3599c7e6a4b781cb6147f0cbdceb2e455c36fe03/timm/models/resnet.py#L66) and store locally

```
wget https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models/releases/download/v0.1-rsb-weights/resnet50_a1_0-14fe96d1.pth
```

2. Patch the `timm.create_model` function that is called by towhee when constructing `image_embedding.timm` and set `checkpoint_path` to downloaded weights:

```py
from functools import partial

timm.models.factory.create_model = partial(timm.create_model, checkpoint_path='resnet50_a1_0-14fe96d1.pth')

towhee_vectors = towhee.glob(*all_frame_paths).exception_safe() \
                        .image_decode() \
                        .image_embedding.timm(model_name="resnet50") \
                        .drop_empty() \
                        .tensor_normalize() \
                        .to_list()
```

It is not good solution in terms of code design but will do the job.

Also if you change `model_name` to other architecture you will need to update `checkpoint_path` in according to that.

Comment: Thanks for this answer I will try it out tomorrow and respond here. Do you also know how to simply use timm instead of towhee for a similar solution as Towhee seems to heavyweight for what I am after.

Comment: You can check out the official examples here: https://rwightman.github.io/pytorch-image-models/feature_extraction/ in your case model initialization will similar to `model= timm.create_model('resnet50', pretrained=False, num_classes=0, checkpoint_path=path_to_downloaded_model)`. The only thing you will be need to implement is reading and preprocessing the images.

Comment: Also found out that the model weights from Timm (when using towhee) will be downloaded to local under ~/.cache at first time run. It will re-used once you have the weights under the cache directory. With the same weights, you are able to reproduce embeddings.