# Recreate Towhee Image Embeddings with Timm

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, computer-vision

For now I have been using https://github.com/towhee-io/towhee for creating image embeddings. But in order to fully understand how Towhee works I wanted to recreate image embeddings with timm (https://rwightman.github.io/pytorch-image-models/).

However I can't seem to get the same result and Towhee is built in a way unfamiliar to me thus I can't find the source code I am missing.

```
EXAMPLE_IMG = "path to some image"
```

#### Towhee code

```
towhee.glob(*[EXAMPLE_IMG]).exception_safe() \
                    .image_decode() \
                    .image_embedding.timm(model_name="resnet50") \
                    .drop_empty() \
                    .tensor_normalize() \
                    .to_list()
```

This gives me a result like below

```
[array([0.        , 0.01364289, 0.00837596, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ], dtype=float32)]
```

While running towhee I looked into ~/.cache/torch/hub/checkpoint for the model weights that were downloaded so that I could use the same.

```
resnet50_a1_0-14fe96d1.pth
```

#### Timm code

Now I tried to recreating the same result purely in Timm.

```
import timm
import torch

# read image
read_image = PILImage.open(EXAMPLE_IMG)
arr_image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(read_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR).astype('float32')
image = torch.as_tensor(arr_image).transpose(2,0)[None]

PATH_RES50_WEIGHTS = "/my_path/resnet50_a1_0-14fe96d1.pth"

model_timm = timm.create_model('resnet50', pretrained=False, checkpoint_path=PATH_RES50_WEIGHTS)
model_timm.reset_classifier(0)
output_cust = model_timm(image)

# same as towhee tensor_normalize()
x = np.array(output_cust.tolist()[0])
gen_vector = x / np.linalg.norm(x, axis=0)

gen_vector
```

The result I get however is different

```
array([0.03503343, 0.01141444, 0.01016041, ..., 0.00766325, 0.02729872,
       0.00292635])
```

I would like to understand how I can recreate the same result as produce by Towhee (the same vector).

This question is somewhat of a next step to: [Reproducible image embeddings from NN (Resnet50)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74111733/reproducible-image-embeddings-from-nn-resnet50/74116530?noredirect=1#comment130862359_74116530)

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer I was looking for here:
https://github.com/towhee-io/towhee/discussions/2215

Thanks to @junjiejiangjjj

Also copying the working code below.

```
import timm
import torch
from PIL import Image as PILImage

from timm.data.transforms_factory import create_transform
from timm.data import resolve_data_config
from timm.models.factory import create_model

model_name = 'resnet50'
model = create_model(model_name, pretrained=True, num_classes=1000)
model.eval()
config = resolve_data_config({}, model=model)
tfms = create_transform(**config)


read_image = PILImage.open(EXAMPLE_IMG)
inputs = torch.stack([tfms(read_image)])
features = model.forward_features(inputs)
global_pool = torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1)
features = global_pool(features)
features = features.flatten(1)
vecs = features.squeeze(0).detach().numpy()
print(vecs)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32990469)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have added the working code to the page.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk As I have provided the answer from the link I would ask you to remove the -1 if it was indeed you who added it.